# PHP - displaying csv uploaded information

Tags: php, css, html, csv

In a nutshell, a user upload a csv file then the below code process it to display on screen.

```
  <?php
                        if (isset($_POST['uploadSubmit'])) {
                        $row = 1;


                        if (($fileCheck = fopen($_FILES["uploadCourses"]["tmp_name"], "r+")) !== FALSE) {
                            while (($data = fgetcsv($fileCheck, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                                $num = count($data);
                                $row++;
                                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                                    echo "<input type='text' value='$data[$c]' />";
                                }
                            }
                            fclose($fileCheck);
                        }
                        }
                        ?>
```

but here's the problem. 
[image]

if they are too many items on the row to be displayed on the screen, it will go on the next line. As you see in the picture **all of the letters are headers, and have their own row (numbers)**, but since that screen size cannot contain all of the row, they will move on the next line, and its mixed up with the columns which creates a mess.

That's the problem. I would like that a custom scrolling bar for that section to be displayed when the row is too large to fit into the screen, and hence keeping the table. It should be large enough so that you can scroll left and right on mobile. Any help would be appreciated.

Any he

Comment: Do I understand you correctly if I say that all the letters are headers, and all the numbers are actual data? Could you give us an example on what the HTML output for the table looks like?

Comment: yes that is correct headers are letters and numbers goes under their respective column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<input type='text' size='2' maxsize='2' value='$data[$c]' />";
```

But you should do it with a real table like:

```
echo '<table>';
while(loop){
    echo '<tr>';
    for (loop) {
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='$data[$c]' /></td>";
    }
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

and also dig a little more into 'html' & 'css'

Comment: thank you, but how i workout that the scrollbar only applies to this section and not the entire page?

Comment: You can set CSS for the table: `width: 500px;`, and `overflow: scroll;` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. it didn't seem to affect it though                           echo '<table style="width: 500px; overflow: scroll;">';